# Vue method not firing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-tables-2

I am working on a project that uses Vue2 (2.5.3) along with [Vue Tables 2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#templates). All I am trying to do is add an anchor around each row, as the  [linked example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#templates) shows, and invoke the `edit()` function. However, it doesn't seem to fire at all and I am not getting any errors. Any idea why this is?

.vue file

```
  <template>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div id="people">
            <v-client-table :data="tableData" :columns="columns">
                <template slot="edit" slot-scope="props">
                    <div>
                        <a class="fa fa-edit" :href="edit(props.row.id)"></a>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </v-client-table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {ServerTable, ClientTable, Event} from 'vue-tables-2';
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import axios from 'axios';

    Vue.use(ClientTable, {
        perPage: 3
    }, false);

    export default {
        methods: {
          edit: function(id){
              console.log("OK", id);
          }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                columns: ['id','name','age'],
                tableData: [
                    {id:1, name:"John",age:"20"},
                    {id:2, name:"Jane",age:"24"},
                    {id:3, name:"Susan",age:"16"},
                    {id:4, name:"Chris",age:"55"},
                    {id:5, name:"Dan",age:"40"}
                ]
            };
        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.VuePagination__count {
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The linked example uses `scope="props"` instead of `slot-scope="props"` as in your code, could be this the issue?

Comment: `scope` has been renamed to `slot-scope` as of Vue 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem I see is that there is no way that I can tell from the documentation to wrap an entire row the way you are proposing with a link. There are several [pre-defined slots](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#slots) you can customize, and you can also use a slot for each column you pass into the `columns` property.

> Templates allow you to wrap your cells with vue-compiled HTML. It can
>   be used in any of the following ways:

Note that says **cells**. So you can provide a template for each individual cell by specifying the name of the column as the slot.

In your example, there is no `edit` column, so nothing is actually rendered.

You could add an `edit` column to `columns`:

```
columns: ['edit', 'id','name','age'],
```

And then your template would work; it would add the font awesome icon to a column in the table.

Here is [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/xzv4k5w51z).

Comment: Bert, Thanks for the help. What you're saying makes sense and works perfectly. However, I am trying to wrap the whole row in anchor or somehow link the row to a url on click. Any ideas?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Nope. I looked for some way to do that and could not see one. Well, I did see one way; you can provide and entirely custom template for the table. I think thats more than you want to do.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Here is the part where they document how to specify a custom template. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-tables-2#register-the-components

Comment: Thanks Bert. Yeah, I saw that, however the docs are lacking. Not sure what should go inside the .js template file.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend No argument there. That is, however, the only way I can think of that would work for what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Bert. I ended up going with your suggestion. Would it be possible to overwrite and anchor all table cells, similar to how we did the newly create edit cell, with the `edit(props.row.id)`? Essentially making the whole row anchored? i.e `<a :href="edit(props.row.id)">{{props.row.first_name}}</a>`

Comment: @AnchovyLegend You could do something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/2w9yr55xmn

Comment: Thanks Bert, that seem to add the anchor to all columns, although it seems to break template functions, i.e.  ```templates: { created_at: function(row) {```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `vue-tables.row-click` event. E.g:

```
Event.$on('vue-tables.row-click', (row) => {
    location.href = "/path/to/asset/" + row.id + "/edit";
});
```

See [Linking a row in a table to a url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47378673/linking-a-row-in-a-table-to-a-url)

Answer (score -2):

Dont use the href on the anchor tag to trigger your click event. Do it like this

```
<a class="fa fa-edit" href="#" v-on:click="edit(props.row.id)"></a>
```

Also, the way you had it with :href="edit(props.row.id)" vue is trying to bind a value to your href attribute. But what you are calling is a function that is not returning any value. I wonder if you check the developers console you might get an error related to compiling the template. Anyways ":" means bind, and i dont think binding is what you want to do here.

Comment: Hi Victor, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, I am not getting the edit event to fire still. Also what if I just want a normal anchor?

Comment: also returning a value makes no difference :/